# How to sort by value of an object inside another object without converting to array?

Tags: javascript, loops, sorting, object, dom

I need to sort an object by the value to an object inside it.
is it possible to sort without converting it to an array first ? 
I create this object by checking if 3 other arrays have its own property and adding it all to one object.

I have tried sorting function inside and out side of for/in loop.

```js
//how i created the object
var htmlDep = document.getElementById("departmentTable")
var tableElem = document.createElement("table");
var tdList = "";
tableElem.innerHTML = "<tr><th class='avdeling'>Avdeling</th><th class='avdeling'>Aktiv Ansatt</th><th class='avdeling'>Ny Ansatt</th><th class='avdeling'>Sluttet Ansatt</th></tr>"
var obj = {}
var distribution = ["manager", "salesMan", "consultant"]

for (var i = 0; i < distribution.length; i++) {
  var work = distribution[i];
  obj[work] = {
    active: 0,
    notActive: 0,
    quit: 0
  } // using 0 as default
  if (active.hasOwnProperty(work)) {
    obj[work].active = active[work]
  }
  if (notActive.hasOwnProperty(work)) {
    obj[work].notActive = notActive[work]
  }
  if (quit.hasOwnProperty(work)) {
    obj[work].quit = quit[work]
  }
  tdList += "<tr><td>" + work + "</td>" + "<td>" + obj[work].active + "</td>" + "<td>" + obj[work].notActive + "</td>" + "<td>" + obj[work].quit + "</td></tr>"
}

tableElem.innerHTML += tdList;
htmlDep.appendChild(tableElem)
//Object example
obj = {
  manager: {
    active: 450,
    notActive: 20,
    quit: 0
  },
  salesMan: {
    active: 150,
    notActive: 5,
    quit: 3
  },
  ceo: {
    active: 50,
    notActive: 55,
    quit: 0
  },
  consultant: {
    active: 5,
    notActive: 72,
    quit: 30
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="departmentTable">
</div>
```

I want to sort the object by the notActive value from high to low inside HTML table

Comment: What is `distribution`?

Comment: In this case distribution is an array ```distribution = ["manager", "salesMan", "consultant"]```

Comment: "*I need to sort an object*" - objects don't have an order. You need an array to sort it.

Comment: okey so my only way is to push it inside a new array and then sort it?

Comment: yes. Something along the lines of  ```Object.entries(obj).map(([a,b])=>(b.work=a,b)).sort((a,b)=>b.notActive-a.notActive)```